# Convertir SQL a LINQ o LAMBDA

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

No sabría como convertir este select en linq o lambda. Principalmente el group by y las subquerys.

```
  select CONVERT(date, tt.FechaHora)
 ,(select MAX(p.FechaHora) from Transaccion p where CONVERT(date, tT.FechaHora)= CONVERT(date, p.FechaHora) and EstadoTransaccionID=1 and TipoTransaccionID=3)
 ,(select MIN(A.FechaHora) from Transaccion A where CONVERT(date, tT.FechaHora)= CONVERT(date, A.FechaHora) and EstadoTransaccionID=1 and TipoTransaccionID=3)
 ,(select count(*) from Transaccion t where CONVERT(date, t.FechaHora)= CONVERT(date, tt.FechaHora) and EstadoTransaccionID=1 and TipoTransaccionID=3)
 ,(select count(*) from Transaccion t where CONVERT(date, t.FechaHora)= CONVERT(date, tt.FechaHora) and EstadoTransaccionID=2 and TipoTransaccionID=3)
 ,(select top 1 c.Observacion from Cierre c where CONVERT(date, c.FechaHora)= CONVERT(date, tt.FechaHora)) 
 from Transaccion tt
 where TipoTransaccionID=3
 group by CONVERT(date, tt.FechaHora)
 order by CONVERT(date, tt.FechaHora) desc;
```

Les agradeceria cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar.

Saludos.

Comment: son muchos subqueries, deberías crearlos cada uno como IQueryable y al final unirlos, o si te urge mucho ejecutalo directo context.Database.SqlQuery

Comment: Como recomendación colega, cuando las consultas son demasiado engorrosas o complicadas y - como en tu caso - necesitan cálculos preferiría crear un `procedimiento almacenado` y llamarlo desde tu aplicación en `C#`; de esta forma se optimiza el rendimiento de tu sistema

Comment: Es verdad seria mejor hacerlo con stored procedure voy a probar hacerlo de esa manera. Gracias a ambos por responder.